# How to override UserLocalServiceImpl in liferay 7 without service wrapper?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I created service wrapper for **UserLocalServiceImpl** and declared a new method inside the service wrapper. But when I explicitly call that method using **UserLocalServiceUtil** the compiler could not resolve this method. So, kindly help me and tell how to override **UserLocalServiceImpl** so that I can define new methods inside it. Thanx in advance..

Comment: Would you please update the post with code snippet what you have tried and what is failing?

Comment: @Abishek Is this somehow a test? You ask _How to override ..._ again and again, without responding to any comment or answer of your previous questions. In addition please read [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: As on many of your other questions: Please don't crosspost or - at least - link your crossposts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Comment: @Olaf:Please comment if you know the answer..

Comment: @AbhishekJain Here's my comment. I know the answer. But I'll only post it here if you properly follow the crossposting procedures for *all* your crossposts as you didn't do this despite being told so multiple times. This also holds for future posts: Stop wasting everybody's time and just stop crossposting all over the internet. This is not respectful to those that volunteer with free help. If it's urgent and needs immediate attention, prepare to pay for services.

Comment: @Olaf: Please tell the answer..I am in urgent need..that's why i crossposted this question..i have no ill intentions behind this..I assure you that in future I will not cross-post ever..now can u please tell me the answer..thanx in advance..

Comment: All I'm asking for is to *link* your crossposts, in *all* directions. Not too much to ask if it's really urgent, right? Specifically after you have been told multiple times that it's considered a lack of respect of those investing their time to help you. But as you never react to any calls for clarification (see the comments above): Why should anybody else react to yours? It can't be urgent, otherwise you'd have given the information that Pankajkumar and Tobias have asked for above, or reacted to any of the other comments on your multitude of crossposted questions. Read the linked meta article

Comment: @Olaf: I deleted this question from other site and i won't crosspost in future..now can you please answer my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
UserLocalServiceUtil.getService()
```

and then cast the result to your custom wrapper type. Then you should be able to call the new method.

Comment: I did what you said and surprisingly compiler could be able to resolve the new method declared inside service wrapper. But, the status of the portlet turned into installed rather than active and it disappeared from the sample category. Please help..thanx in advance..

Comment: I assume you have your service wrapper in different module than the code using it. By introducing the cast you are making your client module dependent on your wrapper module. Compile time you see no errors as long as you have both on classpath. However at runtime you need to tell OSGi about that dependency. That is your wrapper module should export the relevant package and your client module should import it.

Comment: I have heard about import and i did it in one module..but can you explain how to export package from a module?

Comment: That depends a lot on the build tool you are using. If it honors bnd files than simply add it to Export-Package header (see http://bnd.bndtools.org/heads/export_package.html). If you use Eclipse with BndTools it's just drag and drop in the UI. If you use maven-bundle-plugin it's int the POM.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work. You'd change the interface of Liferay's published API and basically be incompatible with any other plugin that assumes Liferay's API.

While you technically have access to all of Liferay's source code and can build a modified version of Liferay, introducing this change, it would mean that no marketplace plugin (that uses `UserLocalService`) would be compatible with your customized version. Any OSGi component can hook into Liferay and get into the callstack for the published API, no OSGi plugin can extend a published interface so that the original interface then has more methods than Liferay's published API.

The best thing you can do if you rely on a separate function call: Create your custom service that makes calls to `UserLocalService`.

Further more, in Liferay 7 you shouldn't use `UserLocalServiceUtil` any more, rather get the service dependency properly injected through a `@Reference` annotation. The *LocalServiceUtil classes are there purely for backwards compatibility and to be used only from *.WAR style plugins.